# Custom validation on radio buttons if not selected | Tailwind

Tags: laravel, tailwind-css, laravel-livewire

How to validate by showing a red ring around the radio button and make text red. Currently I am just showing a validation popup message. See image for a better idea.

**Radio component**

```
<input type="radio" {!! $attributes->class(['border-gray-300 text-gray-600 shadow-sm focus:border-gray-300 focus:ring focus:ring-gray-200 focus:ring-opacity-50', 'border-red-500 text-red-500' => $errors->has($attributes->get('name'))]) !!} />
```

**Livewire view snippet**

```
  <div class="space-y-5">
  @foreach ($ticket_types as $ticket_type)
  <div>
    <div class="relative flex items-start">
      <div class="absolute flex items-center h-5">
        <x-radio-button wire:model="ticket_type" @click="isQuestion = false" id="{{ $ticket_type->id }}" aria-describedby="{{ $ticket_type->id }}_description" value="{{ $ticket_type->id }}" class="h-4 w-4 transition duration-150 ease-in-out" />
      </div>
      <div class="pl-7 text-sm leading-5">
        <x-jet-label for="{{ $ticket_type->id }}_title">
          {{ $ticket_type->title }}
        </x-jet-label>
        <p id="{{ $ticket_type->id }}_description" class="text-gray-500">
          {{ $ticket_type->description }}
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  @endforeach
</div>
<x-input-error for="ticket_type" />
```

**Current look and feel**

[image]

**What I want to achieve** (ignore the checkbox part)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [`conditionally include classes`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#conditionally-merge-classes) on components. So you could do something like:

```
<input type="radio" 
  {!! $attributes->class([

    // these styles are applied by default
    'border-gray-300 text-gray-600 shadow-sm focus:border-gray-300 focus:ring focus:ring-gray-200 focus:ring-opacity-50',

    // these are applied if the name of the component is found in the error bag
    // meaning there was an error
    'border-red-500 text-red-500' => $errors->has($attributes->get('name'))
    ]) 

  !!} />
```

Comment: Thank you Unflux for this but I am receiving the below error 

`BadMethodCallException
Method Illuminate\View\ComponentAttributeBag::class does not exist. (View: /Users/nicotravassos/code/template/resources/views/components/radio-button.blade.php)`

I am assuming because I am missing a RadioButton.php file

Sorry I very new with laravel could perhaps on what this file must consist of and include it in the answer above?

Also will logic above make the text also red?

Comment: Laravel 8 Jetstream livewire stack

Comment: @NicoTravassos Can you update your question with the current code for your radio button component?

Comment: I have updated my code with my current radio button if its not enough I can add invite you to the github project for quick view?

Comment: I reverted back after your snippet threw a error I will update with code you provided me earlier one moment

Comment: @NicoTravassos Are you certain you are using Laravel 8 as the error you're recieving suggests you're not. The [`ComponentAttributeBag::class`](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/View/ComponentAttributeBag.html#method_class) method is available in L8 but not before.

Comment: "laravel/framework": "^8.12", to be exact

Comment: Odd. Maybe try deleting your `vendor` directory and doing a clean `composer install`. I tried in a fresh install using your example and it works.

Comment: I have tried the above and the issue persists

Comment: Please let me know if I can invite you too my private repository if not I will just mark it as resolved because its working for you and I will try fix it.

Comment: If it works for you I am just going to mark it as solved and leave it with with current validation and not make it red. Thanks for the assistance.

Comment: Try it in a clean L8 installation and see if it works. I am curious as to why you're getting that error.

Comment: Could it because the installation is Jetstream and Livewire stack the issue is I have not changed much my in project its basically a new installation about 15 days old.

Comment: Forgot to mention I am using this to output my input error

`@props(['for'])

@error($for)
<div {{ $attributes->merge(['class' => 'mt-2 bg-red-50 p-2 text-xs text-red-800 rounded']) }}>
    {{ $message }}
</div>
@enderror` If its related why its not working.